# graph editor - moving key up and down on particular frame

Tags: graph-editor

is there any option to move a key in one axis up and down in graph editor , like in maya we press shift +click and drag ,

For example if i am moving a key up and down on amy frame its shift's to other frame .

Comment: if you grab the keyframe and click X or Y, it will only move horizontally or vertically, like an object in the 3D view, is it what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you grab the keyframe and click X or Y, it will only move horizontally or vertically, like an object in the 3D view.